# How to know if model is used from Rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-3

In a model, I include a module used by a Rake task.

I would like to do this include only for rake and not for Rails.

I didn't find any method to know if the model is used by  Rails or Rake.

I use Rails3.0.beta3.

If you have any idea i would be glad to hear them :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with defined variable.

You define a variable into your rake task

```
RAKE_TASK = true
```

And in your model you test it with defined?

```
if defined? RAKE_TASK
def your_method

end
```